# My Sound object is using to much memory and causing my application to crash. How can I empty the first half of the objects data?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, memory, memory-management, stream

I'm currently working on a dynamic MP3 player in AS3. The player will also support continuous (in length) radio streams.

Because my player will include a 'seek' bar, I allow the user to seek through the Sound object's data. Now I know that with a continuous stream, data being stored on the users RAM will never stop, as downloading will never stop on a continuous stream. This means, after a few hours of streaming, allot of RAM is being used by my app. I've tested the app on my own machine, running a very high spec, and the app crashes in my browser. When i say the app crashes, I mean the whole of Flash, meaning I have to restart my browser in order to use Flash again. I know my app is the cause as Flash has never crashed in the past. It only does it when my app has been streaming for 2+ hours.

So what I want to do is only allow the user to cache up to an hours worth of audio. After an hour, I want to clear the first half of the sound objects data, meaning that only the most recent half hours audio is stored and available for seeking.

So I have my stream:

```
var soundObj:Sound = new Sound();
soundObj.load(new URLRequest('stream.mp3'));
//ect ect
```

and `sound` is where the data is stored. So my question: How would I clear the first 30 mins of audio from that object?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the `Sound` class is not meant to reliably play "unlimited" MP3 files, which seems to be your case. It is made to play normal MP3 "songs". Two hours of MP3 sound can easily accumulate to be larger than 200 megabytes of data.

But there is a good solution - use `NetConnection` and `NetStream` classes to stream audio instead. There are many tutorials out there. You will also be able to stream your MP3s, just a bit differently - a central server will be involved, which will transcode these MP3s on the fly, delivering it to you in a true "streaming" manner. One of such servers is Adobe Flash Media Server, an overpriced piece of work from Adobe. A lot of free and open-source alternatives exist which will work fine for your purposes - Red5, nginx-rtmp to name a few, that I have tested myself.

Comment: @wvxvw Wouldn't that mean a slight pause in the audio, though? (because I would have to stop one sound object, and start the other)

Comment: @wvxvw I thought about it, but it's not a good solution, even if perhaps an "easier" one, because that would require some sort of backend which can serve and switch MP3 streams seamlessly. So yes, unless you have a proper backend, there will be slight pause in the radio, and even if you overlay two sound objects on top of each other, there will be loss of audio synchronization during some seconds.